# Error in Python Code. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, economics

First time writing Python code. Need some help in graphing this function. It is an Overlapping Growth Model function. Keeps giving an error code even though I am sure the equation is correct. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def olgss(x) :
    numg = ((1-alpha)*A*x**alpha)/(1+n)
    deng = (1+(1/(beta**(sigma)))*(1+alpha*A*x**(alpha-1))**(1-sigma))
    olgk = x - numg/deng
    return olgk

# Set the parameter values

alpha = .3 # share of capital income in GDP
A = 1.0 # productivity parameter
beta = 0.8 # discount factor
n = 0.01 # rate of growth of population
sigma = 0.9 # intertemporal elasticity of substitution from the utility function

# Set the inital condition
state= 0.2

xt = [] # The x_t valudebuge

# Iterate for a few time steps
nIterates = 10
# Plot lines, showing how the iteration is reflected off of the identity
for n in xrange(nIterates):
    xt.append(state)
    state = olgss(state)    
plot(xrange(nIterates), xt, 'b')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('k$t$')
title('Time Path of k$t$')
#savefig('OLGTimePath', dpi=100)
show()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\AChia\Documents\untitled1.py", line 37, in <module> 
   state = olgss(state) 
File "C:\Users\AChia\Documents\untitled1.py", line 14, in olgss 
   numg = ((1-alpha)*A*x**alpha)/(1+n) 
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AChia\Documents\untitled1.py", line 37, in <module>
    state = olgss(state)    
  File "C:\Users\AChia\Documents\untitled1.py", line 14, in olgss
    numg = ((1-alpha)*A*x**alpha)/(1+n)
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power

Comment: Did you notice you are using 'n' for two different purposes?  The 'for n in xrange(...)' will overwrite where you said n = 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add print statements to `olgss(x)`, like so:

```
def olgss(x) :
    print "alpha is", alpha
    print "x is", x
    numg = ((1-alpha)*A*x**alpha)/(1+n)
    deng = (1+(1/(beta**(sigma)))*(1+alpha*A*x**(alpha-1))**(1-sigma))
    olgk = x - numg/deng
    return olgk
```

I get the following output:

```
alpha is 0.3
x is 0.2
alpha is 0.3
x is 0.0126300785572
alpha is 0.3
x is -0.0251898297413
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "globals.py", line 36, in ?
    state = olgss(state)
  File "globals.py", line 13, in olgss
    numg = ((1-alpha)*A*x**alpha)/(1+n)
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

So, it looks like the third call to `olgss()` is returning a negative value, which then feeds back into the next call and causes the error.

Comment: So that means the graph that I need only can go up to two iterates? I know it should increase at a diminishing rate, but with only two points, the graph won't reflect this. Is there a way to get around the negative number exponent?

Comment: I don't think I can help you here. If you're sure your equation is correct, then it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

you have a negative number (`x`) which is getting passed into the function.  You are then raising it to the `alpha` (non-integer) power.  A negative number raised to a non-integer exponent will necessarily result in a complex number -- Something which apparently python doesn't like unless the types involved are complex.

```
>>> (-0.9) ** -0.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
>>> (-0.9+0j) ** -0.9
(-1.0456541539072963-0.3397536300522355j)
```

Comment: `1 - alpha` would only be negative if `alpha > 1`

Comment: You can't just go left-to-right; `**` has a higher precedence than `*`. The problem is that `x` is sometimes negative.

Comment: @Cairnarvon -- Yes, of course.  too tired.  Now I need to figure out why `x` is sometimes negative.

Comment: @MatthewD -- Yes, when I originally read the question (before OP provided a traceback), I assumed the error was on the next line with the `alpha - 1`.  I came up with the explanation and didn't notice on the line before it went to `1 - alpha`.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Print `state`, and you'll see that it becomes negative in the third iterate.  Then, in `olgss`, you have `x ** (1 - alpha)`, which means you are raising a negative number (`x`) to a fractional power (`1-alpha`).  This is not allowed by `**`.